# how to get the name list from the db using function in php

Tags: php, mysql

```
This is my code to get name list from the database but I am not able to get values where is the error can anyone pls help me 

// database connection where php is my database name
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
mysql_select_db("php",$con);
?>

// html body for getting value in option

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
<select name="select" >
    <option>Select College From Here</option>
     <?php $getoptions = get_name(); ?>
    <?php foreach ($getoptions as $key => $value) { ?>
        <option><?= $value ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="sub">

</form>

// function to get name list from the database is this query right or wong ??
<?php
function get_name(){
    $option=array();
    $query="select * From login ";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $option [$row->id] = strtoupper($row->name);
            }
$option;
}
?>
```

Help me regarding this that function not returning me the name from the table and m not able to see the list on select box.. and tell me how can i see the what function is going to return how to get function return value,
can i alert the return value or echo the value

Comment: FYI, [you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which one is best for you.

Comment: You don't know what's wrong because you don't check for errors in your code. Never assume the code is always going to work flawlessly. Use [`mysql_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.error.php) to get a detailed error message from the database.

Comment: You're fetching data as an array and then trying to access it as an object. If you turned on error reporting PHP would have warned you about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this but not tested

```
   function get_name()
{
// your code
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $option [$id] = strtoupper($row['name']);
    }
    return $option;

}
```

check this for test

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        echo $id . "==" . $row['name'];
        echo "<br>";

        $option [$id] = strtoupper($row['name']);
    }
    $option;
    print_r($option);
```

Comment: check last section for testing if everything fine

Comment: i think you missed return $option. so please check now

Comment: function get_name(){
 $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
     mysql_select_db("php",$con);
     $option=array();
     $query="select name from login";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 foreach ($row as $value) {
             
   $option [$value['id']] = $value['name'];
 }
   
 
}
 return $option;
}     i used this code it returning the value but only first charecter not whole string like gaurav in db its returning g only

Comment: this is separate function

Comment: <?php
function get_name()
{
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
    mysql_select_db("php", $con);
    $option = array();
    $query = "select name,id from login";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $option [$row['id']] = $row['name'];
    }
    return $option;
}

Comment: is it work? if work then no need db connection in function

Comment: thanx its working now can u pls explain y i need to put query like this   $query="select name,id from login"; without is its not wrking why

Comment: <?php function get_name()
{
    $option = array();
    $query = "select name,id from login";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $option [$row['id']] = $row['name'];
    }
    return $option;
}

Comment: check this , i think it will work without  db connection in function , if work then inform me, i will tell you details

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141892/discussion-between-shafiqul-islam-and-gaurav-pandey).

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141892/discussion-between-shafiqul-islam-and-gaurav-pandey

Answer (score 0):

should replace 
this

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   $option [$row->id] = strtoupper($row->name);
        }
```

$option;

by   this  code

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $option [$row['id']] = strtoupper($row['name']);
        }
```

return $option;

Comment: Why should the OP "replace" this?  A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.